# Form validation for custom elements in Lit and Typescript

Tags: typescript, lit

I am making some custom web controls in typescript and lit such as submit buttons and inputs and when I try to wrap them in a form in my html, the inputs cannot be seen by the form and the submit button does not try and submit the form. Another UI library called [Weightless](https://weightless.dev/elements/form) is able to do form validation but I am not able to find out how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FormElementBehavior](https://github.com/andreasbm/weightless/blob/master/src/lib/behavior/form-element/form-element-behavior.ts). All the form elements in weightless are derived from this class. It contains all the logic necessary for form to interact with the element.